# Load Text File Into HashMap And Index Elements

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a text file of cars with the following structure:
    21
    Vauxhall
    Corsa
    red

```
19
Vauxhall
Corsa
blue

18
Vauxhall
Corsa
White
```

I can load it into a HashMap but when I load it, it indexes every new line as a new element. How do I change this so after every 4 lines, it indexes?
Is there a way that I can also make it load into a elements such as:

```
id
Manufacturer
carMake
carColour
```

Comment: You could create a car object, and change your map to `<Integer,Car>`. Or you could append manufacturer, carMake, CarColour into a single String and put that in the HashMap. Or you could create a `String []` array...

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you wanted....

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/Desktop/cars.txt"));
    String line = "";
    int i = 0;
    while (line != null) {
        String data = "";
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
            data = data + "," + reader.readLine();
            if (k == 3)
                map.put(i, data);
        }
        line = reader.readLine();
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new POJO class for the `Car` and then populate the data you read from the text file in that POJO.

Also, I don't see any use of a `HashMap` as you are just adding the incremented counter as key. You can use a `HashSet` instead.

Here is the code snippet

```
public class Car {

    private int id;
    private String manufacturer;
    private String carMake;
    private String carColour;

    /* Getter Setters */
}
```

Main Class:

```
Set<Car> set= new HashSet<>();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("cars.txt"));

String line = "";
while (line != null) {
    Car car = new Car();

    line = reader.readLine();
    car.setId(line != null ? reader.readLine() : 0);

    line = reader.readLine();
    car.setManufacturer(line != null ? reader.readLine() : null);

    line = reader.readLine();
    car.setCarMake(line != null ? reader.readLine() : null);

    line = reader.readLine();
    car.setCarColour(line != null ? reader.readLine() : null);

    set.add(car);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to create a `Car` object with those four elements you could do this using `Map` of `Integer` and `List<String>`.

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("cars.txt"));
String line="";
int i=0;
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (line != null) {
    line = reader.readLine();
    if (line == null || line.trim().equals("")) continue;
    list.add(line);
    if (i % 4 == 0) {
        map.put(list.get(0), list);
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
    }   
    i++;
}
```

Comment: @EldoPat123 , did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote will read each line an treat it same, as strings, and as such, you place it in the map. Java is OOP, so use it, create an object, place 4 variables for each line from car string group and then have a HashMap of such objects. Like:

```
public class Car {
private int id;
private String something;
private String type;
private String collor;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getSomething() {
    return something;
}
public void setSomething(String something) {
    this.something = something;
}
public String getType() {
    return type;
}
public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}
public String getCollor() {
    return collor;
}
public void setCollor(String collor) {
    this.collor = collor;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Car car = (Car) o;
    return id == car.id;

}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return id;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Car{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", something='" + something + '\'' +
            ", type='" + type + '\'' +
            ", collor='" + collor + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

}

Make sure you have toString, hashCode and equals method in such objects, they are very important!

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Car` bean and give it a constructor to build the object reading the file lines.

Once create the `Car` will add itself into the map.

```
static class Car{
    String id;
    String Manufacturer;
    String carMake;
    String carColour;

    public Car(BufferedReader reader, Map<Integer, Car> map) throws Exception{
        id = readLine(reader);
        Manufacturer = readLine(reader);
        carMake = readLine(reader);
        carColour = readLine(reader);
        map.put(map.size(), this);
    }

    private String readLine(BufferedReader reader) throws Exception{
        String s = reader.readLine();
        if(s == null){
            throw new Exception("No more line...");
        }
        return s;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        Map<Integer, Car> map = new HashMap<Integer, Car>();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("cars.txt"));
        try{
            while (true) {
                new Car(reader, map);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            // Will be thrown at the end ov the file
        }
        for(int j=0;j<map.size();j++){
            System.out.println(map.get(j));
        }
        System.out.println(map);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should understood what you are actually doing.

This loop that you are using to read file, reads every single line and put in in map under index i (it doesn't care what it actually got).

```
while (line != null) {
    line = reader.readLine();
    map.put(i,line);
    i++;
}
```

So for your purpose you need to discern what data you are excepting in that loop.

```
{
    id = reader.readLine();
    Manufacturer = reader.readLine();
    carMake = reader.readLine();
    carColour = reader.readLine();
    reader.readLine();                   //empty space between data
    ...
}
```

Of course it would be good to check if you are getting any data, like putting it in if statements.

Your next move should be deciding how you want to store that data. There are many ways to do so. For example you could also use another hashMap

```
Map<Integer, Map<String>> map = new HashMap<>();    
...
{
    ...
    Map<String, String> car = new HashMap<>();    
    car.put("id", id);
    car.put("manufacturer", manufacturer);
    car.put("model", carMake);
    car.put("color", carColor);

    map.put(i, car);
}
```

EDIT:
Almost forgot, since your file have space between each car data, there is a need to read that empty line and ignore it